# WCF Error - Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, wcf-endpoint

There are a lot of suggestions on how to resolve this issue but all of them go along the path of editing the config file.

I got my services to work in a testing program (where I can edit the file *app.config*) without any bigger hardship. The problem occurs when I deploy the DLLs to my customer. At their site, I can't (and I won't be able to) edit the config files.

How can I resolve this issue **without** accessing the config file?

Comment: Are you hooking into existing services? Or are you providing the customer both the service and the client?

Comment: @jfin3204 The customer gets a DLL that references an external WCF service. **But** i happen to be the one who's built the external service too.   :)

Comment: SO you are giving them a dll not an entire application?  Take a look at this and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098672/create-wcf-endpoint-configurations-in-the-client-app-in-code

Comment: @jfin3204 Oh, dude. If that works I'm going to feel like a stupid donkey for missing the additional constructors. Please put it as a reply and if it works, I'll green check it. And if you elaborate (if there's anything more to add) I might even go bananas and bounty away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this and see if it helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098672/create-wcf-endpoint-configurations-in-the-client-app-in-code)
For almost everything that you can do in app.config or web.config you can also do it in code.  IF there is more that you need to do include it in the question. WCF has so many bells and whistles that elaborating without some kind of context would turn into a novel.