# Embed app.config containing service info inside the application executable

Tags: c#, wpf

My app.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ESDServiceSoapBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="ESDServiceSoapBinding1">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="ESDServiceSoapBinding2" />
            <binding name="ESDServiceSoapBinding3" />
            <binding name="ESDServiceSoapBinding4">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="ESDServiceSoapBinding5" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://downloadswebregr.mydomain.com:443/ESDServiceWeb/services/ESDEntitlementServiceAPI"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ESDServiceSoapBinding1"
            contract="ESDRegService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPI" name="ESDEntitlementServiceAPI" />
        <endpoint address="http://eotwasqa1.mydomain.com:19081/ESDServiceWeb/services/ESDEntitlementServiceAPI"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ESDServiceSoapBinding3"
            contract="ESDBackupService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPI" name="ESDEntitlementServiceAPI1" />
        <endpoint address="https://downloadsweb.mydomain.com:443/ESDServiceWeb/services/ESDEntitlementServiceAPI"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ESDServiceSoapBinding4"
            contract="ESDBackupService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPI" name="ESDEntitlementServiceAPI2" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I tried embedding this inside the executable using the build action "Embedded Resource" but then my application is not able to read the services information. I want to get rid of it as I want to ship only a single file. i.e. the executable.
I searched for similar questions on stackoverflow and people say, it should be outside so that it can be configured or modified from outside.
Please note that, I dont want it to get changed from outside and just want to embed it.

Comment: You could create those endpoints in code.

Comment: There is no way by which I can use this as an embedded resource?

Answer (score 0):

The basic purpose of the configuration file is to allow the external users to configure something in your application.Hence the configuration files needs to be distributed to the end users.If you intend not to allow changes to the end points ,it has to created inside your code as suggested in the previous comment.

Check the following link.

[Create WCF endpoint configurations in the client app, in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098672/create-wcf-endpoint-configurations-in-the-client-app-in-code)

Comment: [How to: Specify a Client Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731862(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Updated the answer with an example link